# button click event call on page load

Tags: asp.net, events, pageload, buttonclick

I am new in asp.net development, I have problem when page load fired a click event of button is automatically fired.
Will you please tell me why is it happening and what is the solutions for that.

lets

```
protected void butSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(butSubmit.Text.ToString().Equals("Submit"))
        {
        InsertGroup();
        ddlPageSize.Items.Clear();
        FillddlPageSize();
        }
        else
        {
            if (butSubmit.Text.ToString().Equals("Update"))
            {
                UpdateGroupDetail();
                ddlPageSize.Items.Clear();
                FillddlPageSize();
            }
        }
    }
```

I had write a code on click of the submit button ,but when we refresh the page or reload a page the click event of the submit button is automatically fired.

So please tell me why is it happening and what is the solution.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question providing a little more context of the issue you are encountering.  Is the page loading correctly, then you click a button and you're seeing the click event firing.  Or is the click event firing the 1st time the page is loading?  If it is the later you'll probably have to provide code too so people can see what is causing the issue.

Comment: if you 'clicked' a button that is an <asp:button> or <asp:linkbutton> then this fires Page_Load and the server-side event handler (in that order). This is the nature of the ASP.NET Web Forms model.

Comment: Dear i know it very well please read out my question what i am trying to say and what i want to know thanks

Comment: @naval: You are saying that whenever your page load(Either get or post) your button_Click event method also called after page_load method.

Comment: clerify your issue, is it happen only with a postback or with fresh page load.

Comment: when my page load first time then click event of the button on that page is automatically fired and also fired when the page reload  ,i had use the ajex update panel and master apge also .

Comment: please share the code written under page_load event

Answer (score 0):

> i had written a code on click of the
>   submit button ,but when we refresh the
>   page or reload a page the click event
>   of the submit button is automatically
>   fired.

When you refresh the page, the browser will automatically resubmit the state of the page. So if you clicked on the button, and then refreshed the page, the "Clicked" state will be passed back to the server again. This is normal behaviour.

If you want to clear the state and start a fresh, you can click on your URL textbox in your browser and hit enter. This will load the page with a fresh state.